# How to generate a matrix based on a vector efficiently in DolphinDB?

Tags: matrix, vector, dolphindb

I would like to generate a 9000*1000 matrix (m) from a vector (v) with 10000 elements. Specifically, the i-th row of m is v[i:i+1000]. I used the following script and it took 1.3 second to finish. I am wondering if there is a way to make it speed up?

```
v = 1..10000
m = matrix(DOUBLE, 9000, 1000)
timer for(i in 0:9000) m[i,] = v[i:(i+1000)]
```

Answer (score 0):

A matrix is stored in column major order in DolphinDB database. Therefore, operations along the columns are much more efficient than along the rows. If you rewrite your code as follows

```
v = 1..10000
m = matrix(DOUBLE, 9000, 1000)
timer for(i in 0:1000) m[i] = v[i:(i+9000)]
```

It only takes about 20 milliseconds to finish.